# Using pyserial to write and read AT command data from GSM module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gsm, pyserial

Im playing around with a Raspberry Pi, [Breakout Board](http://www.open-electronics.org/a-gsmgprs-gps-expansion-shield-for-raspberry-pi/) and [GSM](https://store.open-electronics.org/index.php?_route_=Breakout/GSM%20Breakout/Small_Breakout_SIM908) module. I'm having problems with the serial read data. It seems to be very speratic, with lots of blanks lines and various odd entries that look to be from the terminal (ssh login field prompt). Im simply trying to read the input response for an AT command. Reading the [AT Command manual](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/media/cooking/images/documentation/tutorial-sim-908/SIM908_AT_Command_Manual_V1.02.pdf) for my GSM, the responses are very specific so I am looking to read just the response im looking for. I am new to serial interfacing like this so any suggestions on best practise would also be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import serial
import traceback
import netifaces as ni
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


def resetModule(resetModulePin):
    GPIO.output(resetModulePin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(resetModulePin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)


def switch(onModulePin):
    GPIO.output(onModulePin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(onModulePin, GPIO.LOW)


def writeAT():
    i = 0
    while True:
        ser.flushInput()
        ser.flush()
        out = ''
        ser.write('AT\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(12)
            print 'GSM Is Up'
            return out
        else:
            i += 1
        if i > 3:
            print 'GSM Down'
            print 'Resetting Module'
            resetModule(resetModulePin)
            time.sleep(5)
            print 'Turning On GSM'
            switch(onModulePin)
            time.sleep(5)
            i = 0



try:
    resetModulePin = 15
    onModulePin = 13

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(onModulePin , GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(resetModulePin, GPIO.OUT)

    ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=115200)

    ser.isOpen()
    answers = ['yes', 'y']
    while True:
        out = writeAT()
        if out != '':
            print out
            break
    question = raw_input('Do you want to powerdown GSM?:').lower()
    if question in answers:
        print 'Powering Off GSM'
        switch(onModulePin)
        ser.close()
    GPIO.cleanup()
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    GPIO.cleanup()
except Exception,e :
    traceback.print_exc()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

OUTPUT (note the blank lines)#Debugging

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo python Newpy
GSM Down
Resetting Module
Turning On GSM
GSM Is Up



Do you want to powerdown GSM?:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ser.write('AAAAAAAT')` per [this](http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/183-sim900-sim908-gsm-module-autobaud-solution).  Apparently the SIM908 on the GSM breakout board tries to automatically detect the baud rate, and you have to give it some extra data in order to do so.

**Edit** Or try [this (post of Tue Nov 25, 2014 11:41 pm)](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=6462) — check the setting of the "charge" jumper on the SIM908.

Comment: I am specifically setting the baudrate, however I will give it a try.

Comment: @iNoob Sounds good!  I saw that you were specifically setting the baud rate on the RPi, but that doesn't mean the GSM has the same setting.  The first thing I thought of when I read your symptoms was "baudrate mismatch!" so I checked on Google to see if it had happened to others.

Comment: I still get odd output `GSM Down
Resetting Module
Turning On GSM
GSM Is Up
IIIIIIIIIIII
Do you want to powerdown GSM?:`

Comment: Im not using an arduino my sim908 doesnt have any jumpers

Comment: @iNoob Sorry - need to log off.  Double-check p. 13 of the manual you linked - I don't see your code waiting for `RDY`.  Also, try `AT\r\n` even though the manual says you only need `<CR>` (`\r`) --- I'm not sure I believe that part of the manual.  Good luck!

Comment: I have already tried '\r\n' with no luck. Im not sure how I woud wait for a command I havent sent and I have a fealing that is for the GSM network off the top of my head but ill look into it and get back to you.